# Warum wurde "daß" durch "dass" ersetzt?

Tags: discussion

Ich habe kürzlich diese [Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/33940/personform-des-verbes-bei-mehreren-m%C3%B6glichen-subjekten/33941#33941) beantwortet.
Benutzer [Jan](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/15318/jan) war so nett diese zu editieren. Nun hat er allerdings "daß" durch "dass" ersetzt. Meines Erachtens ist das der größte Fehler der Rechtschreibreform von 1996. Kennt jemand Hintergründe zu dieser konkreten Entscheidung? "Daß" ist weder auszusprechen wie "krass" oder gar "Hass", es ist ein langes "a". Hat jemand Referenzen?

Nebenfrage: Ist es Konsenz, alles gemäß der Rechtschreibreform beantworten zu müssen?

Comment: Ich kenne genau eine Person, die *dass* mit langem /a:/ ausspricht – das war unser ehemaliger Pfarrer, und der hat jedes /a/ lang ausgesprochen, also auch *nass.* *Dass* und *das* werden von den meisten Sprechern gleich ausgeprochen, und reimen sich in der Regel auf *nass.* Aber es gibt auch einen Post zu alt vs neu; ich suche ihn mal gerade.

Comment: [1](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/11), [2](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/831). 2 ist eindeutig der Wichtigere.

Comment: Die von Jan verlinkten Fragen sollten alles klären, was es hierzu auf Meta zu klären gibt (wenn nicht, bitte eine neue Frage stellen). Die Frage, ob *dass* mit langem *a* ausgesprochen wird, gehört hingegen auf die Hauptseite.

Comment: Danke für eure Hinweise, werde mal schauen, ob ich das transferieren kann.